# how to perform get_by_idx for linkedlist in Rust

Tags: rust, linked-list

I am programing a LinkedList. Here is My Struct, I need some help on performing a get by index (usize) method.

Here is My Struct Code:

```
struct Node<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    value: T,
    prev: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Node {
            value: val,
            prev: None,
            next: None,
        }
    }
}

struct ListNode<T: Clone> {
    length: usize,
    header: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
    tail: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}
```

Now I want to perform a get method to get T by an index:usize, There is a problem

```
impl<T> ListNode<T>

where
    T: Clone,
{
     pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<T> {
        let mut p = &self.header;
        for _ in 0..=idx {
            if let Some(x) = p {
                let clone_p = Rc::clone(x);

                // Problem 1 is here, I want p point to the next
                p = &((*clone_p).borrow().next);
            } else {
                return None;
            }
        }

        if let Some(x) = p {
           let clone_p = Rc::clone(x);
           return Some((*clone_p).borrow().value.clone());
        }

        None
    } 
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `0..idx + 1` can be replaced with `0..=idx`, FYI.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman 

Comment: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to clone the ReCell, Here is the code, any optimization?

```
pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<T> {


    if let Some(p) = &self.header {
        let mut ptr: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>> = None;
        for _ in 0..=idx {
            let v = Rc::clone(p);
            let next = &(*v).borrow().next;
            if let Some(x) = next {
                ptr = Some(Rc::clone(x));
            } else {
                return None;
            }
        }

        if let Some(x) = ptr {
            return Some((*x).borrow().value.clone());
        }
    }

    None
}
```

Comment: the mean idea is: do not try to return a local reference, it is impossible.